# Any frameworks for visualizing a calculation?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing an application in C#/WPF, that performs a lot of calculations for end-user that use the results of these on invoices, etc.

A lot of the inputs for these calculations are a bit obscure for the end-user and also the calculation itself can vary depending on the input.
Still, the end-user should somehow be able to see what those inputs were and also how the calculation is performed.

Are there any frameworks that can help me visualize these inputs and the steps the calculation has taken to get to the end result?

Comment: You may take a look at WorkflowFoundation and its data-flow diagrams